# arrayWithContentsOfFile returns apparently empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c

In http://www.raywenderlich.com/21320/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-ios6 there is a cut-and-paste XML version of a property list. I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"quotes" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.movieQuotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)quoteButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    int array_total = [self.movieQuotes count];
    int index = (arc4random() % array_total);
    NSString *my_quote = self.movieQuotes[index][@"quote"];
    self.quoteText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quote:\n\n%@", my_quote];
}
```

The third-to-last line in quoteButtonTapped is crashing because I'm trying to take the modulus of 0. That means that self.movieQuotes is registering as empty.

`quotes.plist` is stored in the root of the directory, and it appears to be the same, modulo one comment and whitespacing, as in the tutorial.

Any ideas what I am doing to have an empty `self.movieQuotes`?

Comment: is the plist included in the build target?

Comment: Have you verified that your `quotes.plist` file is being bundled with the app? Are you sure it is a valid plist file? Can you view it properly in Xcode? Are you using ARC or MRC? How is your `self.movieQuotes` property defined?

Comment: Does `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` return an empty array or `nil`?

Comment: I created quotes.plist in the root of the app. Inspection of source and other ways of seeing quotes.plist confirms an XML file equal to what I pasted.

Comment: self.movieQuotes is defined in the top method. I believe that the arrayWithContentsOfFile: returns an empty array instead of nil because [self.movieQuotes count] is returning 0 and (correct me if I am wrong) I would not expect [nil count] to run successfully and return 0.

Comment: @Gabrielle, Does creation of a property list in the wizard automatically include the plist in the build target, or is there additional wiring to add the included file to the build target?

Comment: @JonathanHayward Messages to `nil` return `nil`, which is zero. So the value of the expression `[nil count]` is 0. `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` is guaranteed to return `nil` if initialization fails for any reason. Here are some potential reasons: the file wasn't found at the provided path; the file's encoding wasn't understood; the file contained malformed plist data. Can you post the contents of the plist file?

Comment: @JonathanHayward Xcode ordinarily adds plist files to your build, but if you're having problems it doesn't hurt to check. It only takes a moment to inspect the contents of the **Copy Files** build phase.

Comment: I hit this problem. My plist was incorrectly written with <dict> tags instead of <array>.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the memory management semantic of the property in which you're storing the array is `strong`, `retain`, or `copy`. Note that if you use copy semantics, you'll need to implement the setter method yourself if the property type is `NSMutableArray`. (It's not clear from your example whether you really expect or need the array to be mutable though.)

Of course you should also double-check to make sure that you have a well-formed plist file named `quotes.plist` that has an array as its root element, and that it's been properly added to your project's Copy Files build phase.

#### Edit

Finally, make sure that your `viewDidLoad` method is actually being called by adding a breakpoint or an `NSLog` statement.

Comment: In the corresponding .h file I have, "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *movieQuotes;"